# Copy clipboard in Javascript doesn't work on phone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a copy clipboard code here that is working fine on desktop/PC but on phone is doesnt work, can anyone here please help. I'm new on javascript

```
let handleCopyClick = document.querySelector('#copy-username');
   
    handleCopyClick.addEventListener('click', () => {
       
         navigator.clipboard.writeText('<?php echo $username; ?>');

        alert('Username <?php echo $username; ?> has been copied to clipboard!');
    });
```

Comment: The long and short here is that there are a lot of things we don't know here to be super helpful. What phone and browser are you using would help? Also, are you ensuring that the strings being put out from PHP are escaped so that they don't create bad JS in the browser?

Comment: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_clipboard) suggests that the `navigator.clipboard` API has decent support on mobile. How certain are you that the problem you're having is _specifically_ with the clipboard call? Have you tried putting a debug alert just before the clipboard call to see whether this codepath is reached on mobile?